# How do I expand $(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^3$? I want to find the expectation value of this thing

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given $E(x_i)=0$ and each $x_i$ independent, so basically, I want to show that the expectation of this whole thing is simply $E(x_1)+..+E(x_n)$. I'm not sure how to show that other terms of the expansion involves a $x_i$ so it can be cancelled out after the expectation

Comment: I assume they are independent

Comment: Use the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo yes, i forgot to put it

Comment: shouldnt it be $E(X_i^3)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following expansion:

$$(x_1+x_2+\dots + x_n)^3=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^3 + 3\sum\limits_{1\leq i\neq j \leq n}x_ix_j^2+6\sum\limits_{1\leq i <j <k \leq n}x_ix_jx_k$$

Now use linearity of expectation, and the fact that the expected value of a product of independent variables is the product of the expected values to obtain:

$$E(x_1+x_2+\dots + x_n)^3=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n E(x_i^3)$$

Comment: do you see why all the other summands become $0$?